# Java int Array: Find Average, Min/Max, Sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max, average

Edit: I need to do the following with the array: sort, find minimum, find maximum, find the average.

**1) How do I properly access the methods in the other class 2) What variables do I need to initialize in order to make my methods work (since I got the examples from Google)**

I've tried to find examples of how to work with the numbers in an array, but I find it difficult to figure out considering the code is working with different variable names and is largely unorganized and not commented.

This is what I have so far in my methods class:

```
//Grades Array
int[] score = {70,90,80,85,65,55,100,70,40,77,66,55,44};
int number;

//Get
public int getNumber(){
    return number;
}

//Average Grade
public static double average(int[] score, int number)
{
    double average = 0;
    if (score.length > 0)
    {
        average = number / score.length;
    }
    return average;
}
```

Here is my Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Average Method
        OtherMethods average = new OtherMethods();
        int[] number = null;
        OtherMethods.average(number, 0);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I'm all over the place. It's largely a patchwork of examples I've tried to apply.

This is the Sort code I'm using. Adhering my variables to the ones used here would be advantageous, of course, but I'm just not sure where to begin.

```
//Ascending Sort Method
public static void sort(int[] score, int number)
{
    for(i=0; i < num-1; i++) //For each sublist
    {
        min = list[i];
        position = i;

        for (j=i+1; j < num; j++)   //Find minimum
        {
            if (list[j] < min)
            {
                min = list[j];
                position = j;
            }
        }
        temp = list[position];      //Swap
        list[position] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to ask a more specific question. I would recommend **bold**ing it and putting it first

Comment: What is your question? Ask one focused question. If you have multiple, post multiple questions. We can't help you with every part of your assignment here, that's too broad.

Comment: Easy with the downvotes, dang. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8+, Check out the functional [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and in particular [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

For Example, to min/max/average:

```
int min = IntStream.of(score)
                   .min(); // or .max() or .average()
```

and to sort:

```
score = IntStream.of(score)
                 .sorted()
                 .toArray();
```

Comment: But someone landing here may after searching for sorting arrays may not be doing homework.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to sort the numbers you can do something as simple as the bubble sort, which is fairly strait forward compare n to n+1 and switch if need be:

```
void bubbleSort(int ar[])
{
   for (int i = (ar.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
   {
      for (int j = 1; j ≤ i; j++)
      {
         if (ar[j-1] > ar[j])
         {
              int temp = ar[j-1];
              ar[j-1] = ar[j];
              ar[j] = temp;
   } } } }
```

or like you did above the selection sort:

```
void selectionSort(int[] ar){
   for (int i = 0; i ‹ ar.length-1; i++)
   {
      int min = i;
      for (int j = i+1; j ‹ ar.length; j++)
            if (ar[j] ‹ ar[min]) min = j;
      int temp = ar[i];
      ar[i] = ar[min];
      ar[min] = temp;
} }
```

Another thing the way you currently have this set up your getNumber() function has no real use seeing that your number variable is global to begin with.

If you want more help you will have to come up with an actual question.